# Unable to get cytoscape undo-redo to work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape and trying to get it up and running like this [demo](http://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-undo-redo/demo.html). I've converted most of the [code](https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-undo-redo/blob/master/demo.html) to React, and it's mostly working.

The issue that I'm having is to get <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to work just like in the demo (or any other keyboard inputs for that matter). I know that I've correctly registered the plugin, because I can programmatically undo and redo with the `undo()` and `redo()` actions.

I'm not sure what's going on here, perhaps it's an issue with React?

In the sandbox, you can see that the buttons `undo` and `redo` work just fine, but the keyboard <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> do not. Why do the keyboard bindings work in their [demo](http://ivis-at-bilkent.github.io/cytoscape.js-undo-redo/demo.html) and not in my sandbox?

[image: frosty-carson-6fd93?]

Here's what I have,

```
import React from "react";
import cytoscape, { Core as CSCore } from "cytoscape";
import CytoscapeComponent from "react-cytoscapejs";
import stylesheet from "./stylesheet";
import layout from "./layout";
import { initialNodes, initialEdges } from "./elements";
import { TEdge } from "./elements/edges";
import { TNode } from "./elements/nodes";

import undoRedo from "cytoscape-undo-redo";

cytoscape.use(undoRedo);

export default React.memo(() => {
  // Nodes and edges are handles separately
  const [nodes] = React.useState<TNode[]>(initialNodes);
  const [edges] = React.useState<TEdge[]>(initialEdges);

  // Cytoscape instance
  const cyRef = React.useRef<CSCore | null>(null);
  // UndoRedo instance
  const urRef = React.useRef<any>(null);

  const init = React.useCallback((cy: CSCore) => {
    if (!cyRef.current) {
      cyRef.current = cy;
    }

    urRef.current = cyRef.current.undoRedo({
      isDebug: false, // Debug mode for console messages
      actions: {}, // actions to be added
      undoableDrag: true, // Whether dragging nodes are undoable can be a function as well
      stackSizeLimit: undefined, // Size limit of undo stack, note that the size of redo stack cannot exceed size of undo stack
      ready: function () {
        // callback when undo-redo is ready
      }
    }); // Can also be set whenever wanted.

    cyRef.current.on("afterUndo", function (e, name) {
      // @ts-ignore
      document.getElementById("undos").innerHTML +=
        "<span style='color: darkred; font-weight: bold'>Undo: </span> " +
        name +
        "</br>";
    });

    cyRef.current.on("afterRedo", function (e, name) {
      // @ts-ignore
      document.getElementById("undos").innerHTML +=
        "<span style='color: darkblue; font-weight: bold'>Redo: </span>" +
        name +
        "</br>";
    });

    cyRef.current.on("afterDo", function (e, name) {
      // @ts-ignore
      document.getElementById("undos").innerHTML +=
        "<span style='color: darkmagenta; font-weight: bold'>Do: </span>" +
        name +
        "</br>";
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="undoRedoList">
        <span style={{ color: "darkslateblue", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Log</span>
        <div
          id="undos"
          style={{ paddingBottom: 20, position: "absolute", left: 40, top: 40 }}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ zIndex: 99999999, position: "absolute", right: 20, top: 20 }}
      >
        <button onClick={() => urRef.current.undo()}>undo</button>
        <button onClick={() => urRef.current.redo()}>redo</button>
      </div>
      <CytoscapeComponent
        elements={CytoscapeComponent.normalizeElements({
          nodes: nodes,
          edges: edges
        })}
        layout={layout}
        cy={(cy) => init(cy)}
        stylesheet={stylesheet}
        style={{
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code is the omission of the actual key listeners. In the undo-redo demo, the `crtl+z` and `crtl+y` functionality is actually just this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which === 46) {
    var selecteds = cy.$(":selected");
    if (selecteds.length > 0)
      ur.do("remove", selecteds);
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.target.nodeName === 'BODY')
    if (e.which === 90)
      ur.undo();
    else if (e.which === 89)
    ur.redo();
});
```

If you paste this in your code (I tried it after your "afterDo" event listener within "index.tsx", then your undo-redo should work correctly. I had one problem where your code complained about undo-redo being defined twice, but that solved itself after reloading your sandbox.